# Dimension of the spin Hamiltonian for a lattice of particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, lattice-model

I am currently studying the matrix representation of spin Hamiltonians (for now, I'm mainly interested in the Hamiltonian for a group of electrons). I am aware that one of the terms in this Hamiltonian is the exchange term, which is equal to $J_{ij}\mathbf{S_i}\cdot\mathbf{S_j}$ for particles $i$ and $j$, where $J_{ij}$ is the coupling constant. My question is this: since $S_i$ and $S_j$ are just the two-dimensional Pauli matrices for electrons, their product should have dimension $2$ as well under matrix dot-product multiplication. However, the state vector for an ensemble of $n$ spins has dimension $2^n$, so how can its corresponding Hamiltonian only have dimension $2$? I'm interested in finding the time derivative of the spin state function through the Schrodinger equation, but I can't do this if the dimensions of the Hamiltonian and the function seem to mismatch.

Comment: There is a misconception here due to an abuse of notation which is quite common. The procedure is  roughly this: You have a lattice site with two possible states, so the Hilbert space of a single lattice is $\mathfrak h \cong \mathbb C^2$. For $N$ lattice sites, the Hilbert space is $H:=\mathfrak h^{\otimes N}\cong \mathbb C^{2^N}$. If $A: \mathfrak h\longrightarrow \mathfrak h$ is an operator on  the first lattice site, we can lift this operator to $H$ as $A\rightarrow A_1:=A\otimes \mathbb I \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathbb I$, where $\mathbb I$ denotes the identity operator on $\mathfrak h$.

Comment: ...and similarly for operators on the other lattice sites. Often people do not distinguish between $A$ and $A_1$, i.e. they write $A$ although they mean $A_1=A\otimes \mathbb I \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathbb I$. In a matrix representation, then, you see that $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, while $A_1$ is a $2^N \times 2^N$ matrix. If all of this does not sound familiar, I'd advice you to read some basic quantum mechanics book which explains tensor product and tensor product of operators. This is also very briefly explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Heisenberg_model).

Comment: @TobiasFünke it seems like you have written an answer in your two comments. Probably it would be better to post it as an answer...

Comment: @TobiasFünke: Very helpful, thank you! However, I don't understand why all the exchange terms of H should be pushed into the top-left corner. Are there instances in which the exchange terms are distributed differently, depending on what pair of particles is experiencing the interaction? And if so, how can you tell where the matri elements end up?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you mean. Perhaps you should edit the question. Have you checked the Wikipedia link? What's wrong with e.g. the Hamiltonian mentioned there?